# Is it possible dynamically create element in angular 4 like 'Jquery' append element?

Tags: jquery, angular

Example: I get data from database. After i append div and input box **(like Jquery)** to particular **DOM** element.

Answer (score 0):

This content may be useful ;)

https://gist.github.com/caroso1222/1c99aee8c9efe873902a9c590ab7b40a/raw/140ba4f30c90aab3577e99aceb54e2f4e123d06f/dom.service.ts